# Помощь в программировании Java

Tags: java

Нужно найти произведение элементов массива, расположенных между максимальными и минимальными элементами.
Написала код:

```
public class lab5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int []array = {0,13,8,2,26};
        int  max;
        max=array[0];
        int min;
        min= array [0];
        for (int x=0; x<array.length; x++) {
            if (array [0]>max) {
                max=array [x];}
            if (array[x]<min) {
                min=array [x];}

            int pr=1;
            for(int x1=0; x1<array.length; x1++) {
                pr *= array[x1];
            }
            System.out.println(pr);
        }
    }
}
```

Не хочет работать. В чем ошибка?

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать во вложенном цикле? И почему он вообще вложен в цикл по поиску максимума и минимума

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно

1. Запомнить позицию максимального и минимального элементов
2. Вынести цикл вычисления произведения за пределы цикла поиска максимума и минимума
3. Ну и исправить опечатку

   ```
   if (array[0] > max) {
             ^
   ```

```js
int[] array = {0, 13, 8, 2, 26};

int maxIdx = 0;
int max = array[maxIdx];
int minIdx = 0;
int min = array[minIdx];

for (int x = 1; x < array.length; x++) {
  if (array[x] > max) {
    max = array[x];
    maxIdx = x;
  }
  if (array[x] < min) {
    min = array[x];
    minIdx = x;
  }
}

if (minIdx > maxIdx) {
  int tmp = maxIdx;
  maxIdx = minIdx;
  minIdx = tmp;
}
int pr = 1;

for (int x = minIdx; x < maxIdx; x++) {
  pr *= array[x];
}
System.out.println(pr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Конечно ничего работать не будет, в первом if условии не перебирается массив, а используется нулевой элемент массива. 
Лучше будет объявить переменные вот так int min,max = 0; И вынести длину массива в отдельную переменную.

Comment: `int[] array = {-1, -2, -3};`